# Admob Native Templates class is not showing in XML

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I'm trying to use the native ad templates provided by Google, I followed their documentation step by step: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/templates

1. Imported the module
2. added the dependency
3. copied their XML code in my layout

But step 3 is the problem as the IDE is not considering it as a library and thus showing errors

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File > Project Structure > Modules** and then select the **nativetemplates** module.

There you will see **Compile SDK Version**. Make sure that it is same as of your project compile SDK version in the build.gradle (Module:app). See images below:

Image 1 - [PROJECT STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFSaB.jpg)

Image 2 - [nativetemplates compile sdk version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKSA0.jpg)